# Shell Script for collecting user login dates

Tags: logs, users

I'm having trouble making a shell script that will make a list of all the dates when users log in. I want the most recent entries to be on the top (because I know if you just use `date >> logdates` it'll get displayed on the bottom.

So I'd want the columns to be date, sv, and then the dates when logged in - so log in dates from the most recent to the old ones.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you want to do, but have you looked at the `last(1)` command?

Comment: I want to be able to use a shell script (log.sh) that will show me the list of the log in dates from the latest to the earliest. So it'd be the columns: date | log dates. I know this can be added to the .login file but it shows up at the end..

Comment: Again, have you considered parsing the output of `last`?

Comment: You're right - this is exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JosephR indicated in the comments is the command `last` not what you want?

#### Example

Here are the last 5 on my laptop.

```
$ last | head -5
sam      pts/8        :pts/7:S.0       Fri Nov  1 16:22   still logged in   
sam      pts/9        :pts/7:S.1       Fri Nov  1 16:22   still logged in   
sam      pts/7        pegasus          Fri Nov  1 16:22   still logged in   
sam      pts/7        192.168.1.161    Fri Nov  1 10:24 - 15:09  (04:44)    
sam      pts/9        :pts/7:S.1       Thu Oct 31 21:42 - 08:56  (11:13)
```

You can control it like this too:

```
$ last -5
sam      pts/8        :pts/7:S.0       Fri Nov  1 16:22   still logged in   
sam      pts/9        :pts/7:S.1       Fri Nov  1 16:22   still logged in   
sam      pts/7        pegasus          Fri Nov  1 16:22   still logged in   
sam      pts/7        192.168.1.161    Fri Nov  1 10:24 - 15:09  (04:44)    
sam      pts/9        :pts/7:S.1       Thu Oct 31 21:42 - 08:56  (11:13)    

wtmp begins Thu Aug 30 15:09:52 2012
```

What more do you want than this? See the man page for it (`man last`) to see the full details.

**NOTE:** One drawback to the `last` command is the data file that backs it can be [futzed](http://dare.wisc.edu/?q=node/91) with.